# How to get current disk number/name which contains running Windows/Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, winapi, disk

Let's assume that a PC contains several storage devices and we have C++/Qt utility which contains 2 blackbox functions (we don't consider their implementation here):

```
QString get_disk_serial(int drive_number); //for Windows 

QString get_disk_serial(const QString& device); //for Linux. For example, "/dev/sda"
```

I need to know (using C++) which disk is used in the current session (what disk number is active/what device name is active). In my context active disk is a disk which contains the partition, which in turn contains running operating system.

Comment: *"is active"* in what sense?

Comment: I can't really make sense of your question. Running software typically has access to all disks that are currently mounted on the system. I don't think there is any notion of only one being "active" at a time.

Comment: Perhaps they mean the disk on which the process was executed?

Comment: @paddy I doubt it since the only clue we do have is that it's the disk "used in the current session", which suggests that it's scope is larger than that of the current process.

Comment: The closest thing is probably "current working directory" which is a common concept.

Comment: active disk is a disk which contains the partition, which in turn contains running operating system.

Comment: What about a RAID system in mirrored configuration? Which one would be the *"active"* disk here? Or [Spanned Volumes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772180.aspx), where a partition consists of disk space on more than one physical disk? What would the *"active"* disk be in this configuration?

Comment: What about an OS booting off of a network, without any drives in the system at all? Please provide a succinct specification. As posted, the question is based on wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fear that you're trapped thinking in very Microsoft-ish terms.

"The partition with the operating system" makes very little sense on a Unix machine. You have `/boot` with the kernel image, `/usr` with the userspace tools and libraries, `/opt` with optional userspace tools / libs, `/etc` with all the settings... you need all of those (well, except perhaps for `/opt`), and they *can* be located on individual partitions. Which one is "the operating system"?

And Unix does not require the boot partition to be "active" (i.e., flagged active in the partition table) either.

I am frequently working on (virtual) servers where I can't even *see* the partition the kernel is being booted from, or systems where `/boot` is unmounted after the boot process. Then there's the [Logical Volume Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29), at which point things get *really* interesting...

All in all, "active partition" simply does not make sense outside of MS Windows. (Perhaps not even there anymore.) Even AmigaOS could comfortably be spread across multiple volumes back in 1985... ("Please insert volume LIBS: in any drive.")

---

If you think you know the answer to what constitutes "the operating system", you could inspect the mount table to find which device a specific part of the file system hierachy is located on. Both the output format of the `mount` command and the location of any on-file reference of the mount table is, however, platform-specific. (`/etc/mtab` and the output of `mount` on Linux are identical, but `/etc/filesystems` and the output of `mount` on AIX are quite different, both from each other *and* the Linux version of things.)

Comment: There's nothing *"Microsoft-ish"* here. Windows can run in RAID configurations, and supports *spanned volumes*. Windows may or may not reside on a single physical disk.

Comment: @IInspectable: But it's pretty clear where the OP got his original idea from -- Windows' "active" partition and C: drive.